# Angular.js track by ng-options on key of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following object:

```
var orderedFlights = {
   "Airline 1": {},
   "Airline 2": {},
   "Airline 3": {}
}
```

Using an ng-options is it possible to `track by` on the keys of the object?

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-change="flightNumber = airline[0]" 
    name="airline" 
    id="airline" 
    ng-model="airline" 
    ng-options="airline for (airline, flights) in orderedFlights track by airline">
</select>
```

Comment: please put more info about `orderedFlights`. and what do you want?

Comment: @SSH. I want to be able to track by the keys of the object, as I put in the question. Aka, I want to tell the 'track by' statement to use the object keys.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 ng-options="airline as airline for (airline, flights)  in orderedFlights track by airline">
```